# Hide Console When Executing a TProcess

Tags: process, console, lazarus

I'm building a application that uses a `TProcess` called `AProcess` like this:

```
procedure TFormMain.btCompileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AProcess := TProcess.Create(nil);
  try
    AProcess.CommandLine := 'gcc.exe "' + OpenDialog1.FileName + '"'
      + ' -o "' + OpenDialog2.FileName + '"';
    AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poWaitOnExit, poUsePipes];
    AProcess.Execute;
    OutputMemo.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    OutputMemo.Lines.Clear;
    OutputMemo.Lines.LoadFromStream(AProcess.Output);
    OutputMemo.Lines.EndUpdate;
  finally
    AProcess.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But when I click on the button, I got a console window for some seconds and then it exits and all the output of the process is shown on `OutputMemo`, but I've putted the `TMemo` because I don't want the console screen. Then I want to know how I can hide this console screen.

Comment: @Nathan: You should probably remove the Delphi tag, as the question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi. (Delphi has no TProcess class.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the [`TProcess`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/fcl/process/tprocess.html) component that comes with Lazarus. To make a console program start without a console, include the [`poNoConsole`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/fcl/process/tprocessoptions.html) flag in the [`Options`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/fcl/process/tprocess.options.html) property.

```
AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poNoConsole];
```

The options available in that property map very closely to the [process creation flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863.aspx) for the [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) API function, where the flag to use is `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.